# Is there any powershell editor available for sharepoint?

Tags: powershell, tools

I am looking for a free powershell editor that supports intellisense for SharePoint related object and methods. Can anyone suggest me anything?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check these out

1. [The PowerGUI Visual Studio Extension](http://powerguivsx.codeplex.com/) from PowerGUI.
2. [Power Tab](http://thepowershellguy.com/blogs/posh/pages/powertab.aspx)

Comment: I have added the "The PowerGUI Visual Studio Extension" with my VS. In PoswerGUI i am getting sharepoint intellisense but in VS script file i am not getting it. do i need to do any setting?.

Comment: You might need to add "Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" to your profile; which is located in C:\Users\<user_name>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

Comment: @RobertKaucher I can not find this file in my environment. I use win7.

Comment: You may need to create the file. See here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff461033.aspx

Comment: PowerGUI is the way to go.  It has intellisense, and you can run the scripts right in the GUI's own console, and so don't get a limited buffer.  It will tell you when you have mistaken syntax - which is best.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the Powershell ISE from Microsoft, Free and Easy to use though, without intellisense.  However, not really necessary when you consider it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

[PowerSE](http://powerwf.com/products/powerse.aspx) is another free editor well worth considering.

UPDATE: I wouldn't rule out PowerGUI - it's free and with a host of great features. The only issue I had with it was using it during a RDP (Remote Session) - when I remote into a server and use it on the server itself (it's related to the cut/copy/paste which is related to key/screen capture).